My App is not shown on Android tv Google Play
I have Opt in my android tv application in google play console,Even tho I can download it from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musalimurat.metaflix
Its impossible to download it from android tv playstore.
What is the reason?

I tried on 3 separate tv boxes and I am still unable to find the application on google play.
